# Mostrar lucro ou prejuizo em porcentagem negativa

Tags: php, mysql, porcentagem

Considerando os seguintes dados:

```
$despesas = 2000;
$receitas = 100;
$lucroprejuizo = ($receitas - $despesas) / $receitas)*100;
```

Tenho um resultado de: -1900%

Porém se alguma das variaveis receitas ou despesas for zero o calculo da errado porque estará dividindo por zero. Há alguma forma de calcular?
Por exemplo se considerarmos que tive `0,00` de receitas e `300,00` de despesas ele terei **-100%** de lucroprejuizo.

Comment: É incorreto dizer que teve 100% de prejuizo pra um valor que vai de 0 a 300 (e prejuízo negativo, então, nem se fala). Não está na matemática o problema, mas sim nos conceitos. Sugeriria repensar a lógica, com base no uso prático da informação, antes de mais nada.

Comment: Concordo com o @Bacco, a lógica precisa ser repensada. Além do que ele falou, perceba também que se você tiver um valor 100 de receitas e 50 de despesas, a sua variável $lucroprejuizo vai te dar 50% de lucro, quando na verdade o lucro é de 100%.

Comment: Obrigado a todos. @monosan alguma sugestão então neste seu exemplo para que me retorne o lucro correto?

Comment: Sim, @mcasite. Dividir pelas despesas ao invés de dividir pelas receitas.

Comment: @monosan e mesmo assim, fica complicado. Lucro é absoluto, não relativo. Se eu tenho 200 de despesa e 300 de receita, ou se eu tenho 400 de despesa e 500 de receita, o lucro é o mesmo, mas a porcentagem muda Pode até ser que o autor queira um "lucro sobre o movimento", mas há grande chance de não ser isso que alguém vá precisar na prática..

Comment: @Bacco, pois é, a terminologia correta eu não sei qual é. Mas ele quer o valor em porcentagem, seja lucro ou seja qual for o nome mais adequado.

Comment: @monosan tenho minhas dúvidas se o que ele pediu é de fato o que ele quer, de qq forma, se for isso, a resposta do epx resolve. Só acho importante o autor estar alertado pro problema (e isso já fizemos, agora é com ele).

Answer (score 1):

O caso de $despesa = 0 você teria de filtrar com uma condição "if", porque ela representa um lucro infinito (receita sem qualquer despesa). Para eliminar a divisão por zero quando a receita é igual a zero, a fórmula pode ser modificada para:

```
100 * ($receitas / $despesas) - 100
```

Nesta fórmula, se receita=300 e despesa=250, o resultado é +20 (lucro de 20%). Se receita=0 e despesa é diferente de zero, o resultado é sempre -100%.